# Getting data from Swapi API https://swapi.co/api/people/ using spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

when I use the RestTemplate and the Getforobject() method I get an error 500 code when running my spring boot. How can I consume this API using springboot?

```
package nl.qnh.qforce.controller;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class PersonController {

    private static String url = "https://swapi.co/api/people/";

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @GetMapping("/people")
    public List<Object> getPeople(){
        Object[] people = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Object[].class);
        return Arrays.asList(people);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try use java.net.HttpURLConnection for get the results

Comment: Hey, do you resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would advise first checking if manually calling provided url returns expected response. You can use curl, postman or any other similar tool. In case call on provided url returns response, provide us with more context from your application, so we can assess which part is responsible for 500 error.